# AVFoundation captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer Delay

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cmsamplebuffer, avcaptureoutput

I am using **AVFoundation captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer** to extract an image then to be used for a filter.

```
  self.bufferFrameQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "bufferFrame queue", qos: DispatchQoS.background,  attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit)

  self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
  if self.session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput) {
       self.session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
       self.videoDataOutput!.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
       self.videoDataOutput!.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
           self.videoDataOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.bufferFrameQueue)
  }



 func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        connection.videoOrientation = .portrait

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.cameraBufferImage = ciImage
        }
}
```

Above just updates **self.cameraBufferImage** anytime there's a new output sample buffer.

Then, when a filter button is pressed, I use **self.cameraBufferImage** as this:

```
  func filterButtonPressed() {

    if var inputImage = self.cameraBufferImage {

      if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone") {
        currentFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        currentFilter.setValue(1, forKey: "inputIntensity")
        if let output = currentFilter.outputImage {
          if let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output, from: inputImage.extent) {

            self.filterImageLayer = CALayer()
            self.filterImageLayer!.frame = self.imagePreviewView.bounds
            self.filterImageLayer!.contents = cgimg
            self.filterImageLayer!.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill
            self.imagePreviewView.layer.addSublayer(self.filterImageLayer!)

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When above method is invoked, it grabs the 'current' **self.cameraBufferImage** and use it to apply the filter.  This works fine in normal exposure duration times (below 1/15 seconds or so...)

### Issue

When exposure duration is slow, i.e. 1/3 seconds, it takes a awhile (about 1/3 seconds) to apply the filter.  This delay is only present upon the first time after launch.  If done again, there is no delay at all.

---

**Thoughts**

I understand that if exposure duration is 1/3 seconds, didOutputSampleBuffer only updates every 1/3 seconds.  However, why is that initial delay?  Shouldn't it just grab whatever **self.cameraBufferImage** available at that exact time, instead of waiting?

1. Queue issue?
2. CMSampleBuffer retain issue? (Although on Swift 3, there is no CFRetain)

---

**Update**

[Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput)

> Delegates receive this message whenever the output captures and
>   outputs a new video frame, decoding or re-encoding it as specified by
>   its videoSettings property. Delegates can use the provided video frame
>   in conjunction with other APIs for further processing.
>
> This method is called on the dispatch queue specified by the output’s 
>   sampleBufferCallbackQueue  property. It is called periodically, so it
>   must be efficient to prevent capture performance problems, including
>   dropped frames.
>
> If you need to reference the CMSampleBuffer object outside of the
>   scope of this method, you must CFRetain it and then CFRelease it when
>   you are finished with it.
>
> To maintain optimal performance, some sample buffers directly
>   reference pools of memory that may need to be reused by the device
>   system and other capture inputs. This is frequently the case for
>   uncompressed device native capture where memory blocks are copied as
>   little as possible. If multiple sample buffers reference such pools of
>   memory for too long, inputs will no longer be able to copy new samples
>   into memory and those samples will be dropped.
>
> If your application is causing samples to be dropped by retaining the
>   provided  CMSampleBuffer  objects for too long, but it needs access to
>   the sample data for a long period of time, consider copying the data
>   into a new buffer and then releasing the sample buffer (if it was
>   previously retained) so that the memory it references can be reused.

Comment: Hi did you get any solution? When I change device type front to back or back to front some of the frames dropped and freeze for a 3-4 sec which is noticeable easily.